# one function accepts different models and dynamically creates object according to that in django

Tags: django, function, python-2.7, import

I want to create a function like

```
def dynamic_model(model_name,**kwargs)
    obj=model_name.object.create(**dct)
    return obj
```

because I don't want to do again and again create object  and save them in database.you pass model name in function and object create according to passed **kwargs. How I import path runtime and what would be the body of function.

**And main thing I don't know which model and from where it import .all things get visible me at runtime so how can I import the path regarding to model name in function  **

Comment: There will be no easy way, because you will have to handle database tables on your own (maybe use django-south for that), because Django creates the database tables based on "static" models.

Comment: What's the point of this function? Why is `dynamic_model(MyModel, mydict)` any better than `MyModel.objects.create(**miydict)`?

Comment: actully i have a form which inputs are save in diffrent models' fields.suppose in future i want to add another field which hit one more model then i have to create one more save process for that model.thats why i want to creat a fuction which accept model name and value and save in database correspond to that model and models field

Answer (score 2):

You could use `eval()` here. But keep in mind, this solution comes with a red alert.

```
def dynamic_model(model_name,**kwargs)
    obj = eval(model_name + ".object.create(**dct)")
    return obj
```

`eval()` interprets string as code. And because of this you need to be highly cautious while using this. For example, always make sure that the string which comes to eval is never a direct user input. And also sanitize the string being passed.

It can be used safely though. Read about it [here](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html).

Comment: how can i know the path of that model ?how can i import that?

Comment: If you know the possible app module names, then it's advisable to import them before hand in this file.
Ex- `from app.models import *`

Comment: @user2576049 Kindly close the question by [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the point of this function, but still if you want to do something like this you should never use `eval()` for this.

You could try this

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model

def dynamic_model(app_name, model_name,**kwargs)
    # app_name and model_name should be plain strings
    # the name of your app and model
    klass = get_model(app_name, model_name)
    obj = klass.object.create(**kwargs)
    return obj
```

You don't have to import anything you just need to pass plain strings i.e. the name of your app and model and it will return the required model class

Comment: thank you so much buddy ... U have saved a lot of effort for me.